# SQL Server get most popular products

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a simple question. On my main page I need to display top 10 most popular products. I have millions of records in my sales table.

I am thinking of creating an indexed view in the database to maintain data in computed fashion and then query data from that view.

What are your thoughts ? Is there a better solution ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Imagine if a colleague came up to you and asked you this question exactly the same way. Would you have any clarifying questions? Would you want any more detail? Or would you be confident that you could give them a solution based on the little info given to you?

Comment: What measureable quality would make a solution "better" to you?

Comment: Thanks for your notes Tab I appreciate that . Feel free to give me advice how to ask question in cleaner way :)

Comment: Another thing to think about: most popular as of when?  From the beginning of your site?  Over the last week?  If it's the latter, you may be able to get away with simply restricting the data down to a much smaller subset of data and then doing calculations on it without having to go through index/view/datawarehouse hoops.  After all, if you've got an index on your sales table, and only have 2000 sales per week, it becomes a lot easier to get "most popular product" in real-time.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

An indexed view can work well for this... but remember now every update to the sales table will cause the view to recalculate. This can make your sales updates very expensive/slow.

What I might do instead is create a separate table for this that only updates periodically. If you already have a data warehouse, this is the place for that table. Then you can pull your popular product info from this much smaller table.

Comment: Thanks for response. So you are hinting on creating a job that periodically calculates data and fills the table right ?

Comment: That is correct. Then make it clear to anyone who uses the data that it can be stale.